# WinApi Scrollbar Handling

Tags: winapi, scrollbar, handle

I want to create a nice user interface for my project. I Create a window, then I create a child window which is the main window for the interface functions. So... I have those two windows, in the child window i want to add a scroll bar. I created a Scrollbar class:

```
class Scrollbar
{
public:
    HINSTANCE hInstance;
    HWND hwnd;
    SCROLLINFO si;
    Scrollbar(HWND Scroll_hwnd, HINSTANCE hInstance, HWND hwnd, SCROLLINFO si, RECT Child_rect, int iHThumb);
    SCROLLINFO Initialise(SCROLLINFO si, RECT rect);
    ~Scrollbar();
};
```

in the constructor i've basicaly have a CreateWindow function:

```
Scroll_hwnd = CreateWindow(
L"SCROLLBAR", 
(LPCWSTR)NULL,
 WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SBS_HORZ | SBS_BOTTOMALIGN,
 Child_rect.left,Child_rect.top,Child_rect.right-iHThumb,Child_rect.bottom,
 hwnd,
 NULL,
 hInstance,
 NULL);

SetScrollRange( Scroll_hwnd, SB_CTL, 0, 10, FALSE);
```

So the scroll gets created but now I want to handle it somehow so I do something like this in my child window CALLBACK func:

```
case WM_HSCROLL: 
    {

    GetScrollInfo( hwnd, SB_VERT, &si );

    int position = si.nPos;

    switch( LOWORD( wParam ) ) 
    {

    case SB_LINELEFT:
        if( position > 0 ) 
        {
            position--;
        }
        break;
    case SB_LINERIGHT:
        if( position < 10 ) 
        {
            position++;
        }
        break;
    ZeroMemory( & si, sizeof( si ) );
    si.cbSize = sizeof( SCROLLINFO );
    si.fMask = SIF_POS;
    si.nPos = position;

    SetScrollInfo( hwnd, SB_VERT, & si, TRUE );
}
```

Dunno but in my opinion there everything fine... the position variable gets incremented just fine but the scroll is still in the starting position. Any idea whats wrong? 
Also when I try to do something like this:

```
Scrollbar *s1;
s1 = &scroll;
```

(...)

```
GetScrollInfo( hwnd, SB_VERT, s1->si );
```

I get an conversion error (SCROLLINFO TO LPSCROLLINFO)

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a horizontal scroll bar, but you are getting/setting vertical scroll bar values in your callback.  Change `SB_VERT` to `SB_HORZ`.

As for the compiler error, you are indeed passing a `SCROLLINFO` where a `SCROLLINFO*` is expected.

Change this:

```
GetScrollInfo( hwnd, SB_VERT, s1->si );
```

To this:

```
GetScrollInfo( hwnd, SB_HORZ, &(s1->si) );
```

Or this:

```
GetScrollInfo( hwnd, SB_HORZ, &(scroll.si) );
```

Comment: Thanks man! That helped! :) I lost 2h searching the mistake and changing my code and the answer was so simple. Damn :/ One more time, thanks!